# How to set session proxy in Azure Python SDK for NetworkManagementClient?

Tags: python, azure, proxy

I want to be able to use a proxy server with Azure Python SDK `NetworkManagementClient (NMC)`. I saw that the `NMC` has a `_client` attribute of type `msrest.service_client`, which includes a `config` attribute of type `NetworkManagementClientConfiguration` which inherits from `AzureConfiguration`, which itself has a proxies attribute of type `msrest.pipeline.ClientProxies`.

Given the above it seems that configuring a proxy is possible, but I don't understand the proper way to set it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, msrest is using requests, so I assume you read [proxies documentation of requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#proxies). Note too that a `requests.Session` object has a `trust_env` attribute that is `True` by default to read some env variables like `HTTP_PROXY`.

The configuration of a client has a `proxies` attribute, being as you mentioned a `ClientProxies` class. This class has a `proxies` dict attribute itself and a `add` method to add in this dict. This class has also a `use_env_settings` boolean attribute.

Assuming you have a `client` variable instance of `NetworkManagementClient`, so you can either:

- Simply use HTTP_PROXY / HTTPS_PROXY. Note that you can disable env vars using

  `client.config.proxies.use_env_settings = False`

  This is just an alias to `trust_env` of requests.
- Define your own proxy:

  `client.config.proxies.add('http', 'http://example.org:8080')`

  The call will actually be equivalent to

  `session.get(url,proxies={'http': 'http://example.org:8080'})`

(I own msrest at MS)